# Can I include/exclude certain declaration files from a @types devDependency?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a devDependency in my package.json with code that is very similarly named to mine. The compiler often confuses a name I want to import as a name in a declaration file, and vice versa. Due to the nature of my code, I don't need most of these overloaded declarations, I just need a small subset.

As an example, let's say I am depending on [@types/sparql-http-client](https://github.com/DevExpress/DefinitelyTyped/tree/047819443546cf8dfd7c46490309554eaf7eef77/types/sparql-http-client) (this link goes to `DevExpress/DefinitelyTyped/types/sparql-http-client` to give you an idea of their project structure). Is there a way I could include the [ResultParser declaration file](https://github.com/DevExpress/DefinitelyTyped/blob/047819443546cf8dfd7c46490309554eaf7eef77/types/sparql-http-client/ResultParser.d.ts) but exclude the others?

If this can't be done, I was planning on this workaround: copying and pasting that declaration file into my project and removing `@types/sparql-http-client` as a devDependency.

(I'm including npm as a tag to this question because it might be able to provide a solution)